# Oracle SQL - Round decimal to 2/3 based on conditon

Tags: sql, oracle, rounding, truncate

Hello I have a requirement where I need to round decimals based on the condition:

If the first 2 digit after the decimals is not 00 then I need to round it to 2 place, otherwise 3 places.

Example:
`1.232133342 => ROUND(1.232133342,2)` //this will work

but if the number is `1.00233231213` value should be `1.002` //round to 3 digit

if the number is `1.0000223123312`then the value should be `1.00002`

Is there any function? Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This rounds to at least two digits, maybe more by counting the number of leading zeros in the fractional part using a RegEx

```
round(x, greatest(2, length(regexp_substr(x,'\.0*'))))
```

see [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=02e641e425cc717c6e4cd8f792e99d43)

Comment: What about his last condition? `if the number is 1.0000223123312then the value should be 1.00002`

Comment: @Nebi: Yep, the question was a bit misleading: *round it to 2 place, otherwise 3 place*. Fixed ;-)

Comment: Yery nice answer! +1

Comment: @Nebi: Still way too complicated, there's no need for MOD/ABS :-)

Answer (score 3):

Subtract the floor of the number from the number, and check if it's less than `.01`.

```
CASE WHEN ABS(number) - FLOOR(ABS(number)) < .01 THEN ROUND(number, 3)
     ELSE ROUND(number, 2)
END
```

Comment: This fails for negative values

Comment: I added `ABS()` to fix that.